# Integrating over a sphere

Tags: vector-calculus

We are trying to integrate a vector function over a sphere. To do this we changed it to spherical coordinates and then tried to integrate it. Unfortunately we get the error message shown on the image below.
[image]

The codes that we used are the following:

```
Simplify[
  ToSphericalCoordinates[
     {q*X/(4*π*ϵ*(X^2+Y^2+Z^2)^(3/2)), 
      q*Y/(4*π*ϵ*(X^2+Y^2+Z^2)^(3/2)), 
      q*Z/(4*π*ϵ*(X^2+Y^2+Z^2)^(3/2))}]]

Integrate[
  Sqrt[q^2/((X^2+Y^2+Z^2)^2 ϵ^2)]/(4 π), 
  ArcTan[(q Z)/((X^2+Y^2+Z^2)^(3/2) ϵ), Sqrt[(q^2 X^2+Y^2))/((X^2+Y^2+Z^2)^3 ϵ^2)]], 
  ArcTan[(q X)/((X^2+Y^2+Z^2)^(3/2) ϵ), (q Y)/((X^2+Y^2+Z^2)^(3/2) ϵ)], 
  {X, Y, Z} ∈ Sphere[{0,0,0},{r}]]
```

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: The radius of the sphere should not be a list: `Sphere[{0,0,0},r]` doesn't produce any errors

Comment: Ah we got it now. Thanks a lot!